# Implement Stringer interface using value or pointer receiver

Tags: go

I tried to implement the `Stringer` interface on my type as follow:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type IPAddr [4]byte

// TODO: Add a "String() string" method to IPAddr.
func (o IPAddr) String() string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("%v.%v.%v.%v",  o[0], o[1], o[2], o[3])
}

func main() {
    hosts := map[string]IPAddr{
        "loopback":  {127, 0, 0, 1},
        "googleDNS": {8, 8, 8, 8},
    }
    for name, ip := range hosts {
        fmt.Printf("%v: %v\n", name, ip)
        fmt.Printf("%v\n",  ip.String())
    }
}
```

In the code above, I used a value receiver to implement the `String()` method. The `Printf` recognised my implementation and called the correct `String` function on my type.

Output:

```
googleDNS: 8.8.8.8
8.8.8.8
loopback: 127.0.0.1
127.0.0.1
```

Then I updated my code to use pointer receiver:

```
func (o *IPAddr) String() string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("%v.%v.%v.%v",  o[0], o[1], o[2], o[3])
}
```

The output of the updated code:

```
loopback: [127 0 0 1]
127.0.0.1
googleDNS: [8 8 8 8]
8.8.8.8
```

The `Printf` method didn't call my `String` method anymore. The output told me that `Printf` use the default `String` method of the type. However, when I called `ip.String()`, my method was used.

Can someone explain to me this behaviour, please? As far as I know, we can implement methods of interfaces by both value and pointer receivers.

Thank you.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The `%v` conversion specifier will read any method satisfying the `Stringer` interface.  For this to happen, however, that method must exist in the method set of the value.

For a value of type `T`, its method set contains any methods that receive a value of that type `T`:

```
func (t  T) Foo()    //     in the method set of T
func (t *T) Bar()    // not in the method set of T
```

For a pointer of type `*T`, its method set contains both methods that receive a value of type `T` and a pointer of type `*T`:

```
func (t  T) Foo()    //     in the method set of *T
func (t *T) Bar()    //     in the method set of *T
```

In `main`, you have a value identified as `ip` with type `IPAddr`, so the first set of commented code above applies.

Your first example will work because the method receiver of the `String` method has type `IPAddr`.

In the second example, the method receiver of the `String` method has type `*IPAddr`, which means it's not in the method set of `ip`, which has type `IPAddr`.

In summary:

```
            | String() Method | fmt.Print, fmt.Printf, etc.
 Input Type | Receiver        | calls String() implicitly
 ========== | =============== | ===========================
   *IPAddr  |     IPAddr      | Yes
            |    *IPAddr      | Yes
 ---------- + --------------- + ---------------------------
    IPAddr  |     IPAddr      | Yes
            |    *IPAddr      | No
```

You might be wondering why this occurs.  It turns out that some values might not be addressable, so a method receiver with type `*IPAddr` can't receive a value that has no address.  For example, try executing `IPAddr{}.String()` with an `*IPAddr` method receiver.  It will fail to compile because a literal value has no address.  If you instead used `(&IPAddr{}).String()`, it would work because now you have a pointer `*IPAddr` created using `&IPAddr{}`, and if you used a non-pointer receiver `IPAddr`, then it would work whether the `IPAddr` was addressable or not.

Comment: Thank you, I now understand the behaviour of Go.

Comment: "The %v conversion specifier will read any method satisfying the Stringer interface." I wish the standard library phrased it like this.

Answer (score 3):

The thing is that your map contains type `IPAddr` which does not have a `String()` function, only `*IPAddr` does. This means that you do **not** pass a `Stringer` interface to the print function, so it uses default printing.

One peculiarity in Go is that you can still do the following:

```
var ip IPAddr
ip.String()
```

because in this case Go is smart enough to know that it can call the `String()` function on the address of the variable. Go can automagically take the address of a variable for calling a function on it.

On the other hand, you would not even be allowed to call `String()` on an `IPAddr` contained in a map because getting something out of a `map` with `[]` returns a copy that is not addressable. [Here is an example](https://play.golang.org/p/WoFsLhncWYa) to illustrate these properties:

```
package main

import "fmt"

type IPAddr [4]byte

func (o *IPAddr) String() string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("%v.%v.%v.%v", o[0], o[1], o[2], o[3])
}

func main() {
    var ip = IPAddr{1, 2, 3, 4}

    // printing the value does not call String() because we pass type IPAddr,
    // not type *IPAddr
    fmt.Printf("%v\n", ip)

    // but we can call String() on the variable because Go knows how to get its
    // address
    fmt.Println(ip.String())

    m := map[int]IPAddr{1: IPAddr{1, 2, 3, 4}}
    fmt.Println(m[1])
    // the following is a compile-time error because Go cannot take the address
    // of things in the map, because the []-operator returns only a copy of the
    // IPAddr
    //fmt.Println(m[1].String())
}
```